# Restricting routes to nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am trying to create nested resources where the sub-resource doesn't have an existence of its own.  e.g., an `Address` resource which is linked to a `Person`.

My route declaration looks like so:

```
map.resources :persons,
:has_many => :addresses
```

This gives me the following routes:

```
             person_addresses GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses                  {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"index"}
   formatted_person_addresses GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses.:format          {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"index"}
                              POST   /persons/:person_id/addresses                  {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"create"}
                              POST   /persons/:person_id/addresses.:format          {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"create"}
           new_person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/new              {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"new"}
 formatted_new_person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/new.:format      {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"new"}
          edit_person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id/edit         {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"edit"}
formatted_edit_person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id/edit.:format {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"edit"}
               person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id              {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"show"}
     formatted_person_address GET    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id.:format      {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"show"}
                              PUT    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id              {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"update"}
                              PUT    /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id.:format      {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"update"}
                              DELETE /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id              {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"destroy"}
                              DELETE /persons/:person_id/addresses/:id.:format      {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Now I want to make sure that a person's addresses are read-only, i.e., I only want the `show` and `index` actions for an address.

I tried this:

```
  map.resources :persons,
  :has_many => :addresses,
  :collection => { :addresses => [ :show, :index ] }
```

and got this error:

```
(in /home/rmk/app)
rake aborted!
Invalid HTTP method specified in route conditions: {:method=>:show}

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

EDIT:
My main problem was that I was not using the code block properly (I wanted to use has_one etc. as much as possible).  So my `persons` routes look like this (somewhat contrived example):

```
map.resources :persons, :has_one => :ssn, :except => [:new, :edit] do |person|
 person.resources :addresses, :only => [:index, :show]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
map.resources :persons do |person|
  person.resources :addresses, :only => [:index, :show]
end
```

This creates addresses as a nested resource of persons, but only makes the index and show views available.

Comment: Awesome, Karl, thank you. As I have explained in the edit above, I was not using the code block properly ( I wanted to specify other constraints on :persons using :has_one, :has_many etc, and resort to the code block only when necessary).